# Earth Engine - enforce minimum distance between sample points

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a group of sample points but need to enforce a minimum distance of 500m between the points. I have come about this approach from Noel Gorelick: https://medium.com/google-earth/random-samples-with-buffering-6c8737384f8c, where he outlines how this could be done but not totally.

In caveat #7, he explains:
"Suppose you already have points and just want to select a subset that meets the buffering criteria. In that case, you can use reduceRegions with a max reducer on the random image, grouping by the cells image. The max reducer will allow you to specify additional inputs (e.g.: covariates or pixel coordinates) to carry along with whatever maximum it finds."

This is exactly what I want to do but can't figure it out.
Here is what I have so far:

```
var seed = 1

var proj = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(cellSize)
var cells = ee.Image.random(seed).multiply(100000).int().clip(geometry).reproject(proj)
Map.addLayer(cells.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'cells')
print(cells, 'cells')

// Generate another random image and select the maximum random value 
// in each grid cell as the sample point.
var random = ee.Image.random(seed).multiply(1000000).int()
print(random)
var maximum = cells.addBands(random).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.max())
  
// Find all the points that are local maximums.
var points = random.eq(maximum).selfMask().clip(geometry)
print(points, 'point')

random = random.addBands(cells)
print(random)
var subset = random.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max().group(1),
  collection: stratified,
  scale: 30
})
```

The last part is not selecting a subset from the stratified collection as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

With an existing set of points, its often easier to just mask the random image with the points you've got and proceed in the standard way (reduceToVector the maximum image).

```
// A set of "existing" points we're going to select from.
var stratified = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry, 1000)
Map.addLayer(stratified)

var seed = 1
var cellSize = 5000
var proj = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(cellSize)
var cells = ee.Image.random(seed).multiply(100000).int().clip(geometry).reproject(proj)
Map.addLayer(cells.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'cells')

// Generate another random image and select the maximum random value 
// in each grid cell as the sample point.
var existingPointsMask = ee.Image(0).byte().paint(stratified, 1)
var random = ee.Image.random(seed).multiply(1000000).int().updateMask(existingPointsMask)
var maximum = cells.addBands(random).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.max())
  
// Find all the points that are local maximums.
var points = random.eq(maximum).selfMask().clip(geometry)
// Force the projection just so we can see the individual points that have been selected.
Map.addLayer(points.reproject(ee.Projection("EPSG:4326").atScale(100)), {color: "white"})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc39af982f804f4a96b8e68b6bec78cd